# iPhone UIButton to title text?

Tags: iphone, ipad, xamarin.ios, uibutton, title

I have a UIButton created in UIBuilder. It is set to "**Custom**"

In code I add the title and images. The **button works**, images change on the click of the button. **But no text appears**?

```
btnAddRecord.SetTitle("Add Record",UIControlState.Normal);
btnAddRecord.SetTitleColor(UIColor.White,UIControlState.Normal);
btnAddRecord.SetBackgroundImage (UIImage.FromBundle ("Images/lowerBarButton.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
btnAddRecord.SetImage (UIImage.FromBundle ("Images/lowerBarButton.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
btnAddRecord.SetImage (UIImage.FromBundle ("Images/lowerBarButtonEnabled.png"), UIControlState.Highlighted);
```

Comment: What language is this..?

Comment: It's Microsoft.NET MonoTouch allows iPhone apps to be written in c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax seems really weird.

Try `[button setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal]`

Comment: It's MonoTouch for iPhones. C#.NET for the iPhone platform.